# Button should be clickable only if the popup is not there

Tags: c#, xamarin, button, xamarin.forms

I have a clicked command from my xaml:

```
 <Button Image="Info_icon"                         
         Clicked="Info_Clicked"/>
```

This is the method from code behind:

```
 void Info_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MyLayout.Children.Add(new Objects.ShowInfo());           
    }
```

When you click the button there is a popup that shows but I only want that button to work if the popup is not there.

Comment: In `Info_Clicked` deactivate the button when it is executed the first time.

Comment: But that means I cant click it again? I need to be able to click it again when I've removed the popup @Greg

Comment: You could add a click event to ShowInfo that enables the Button again. Or bind the visibility of ShowInfo with the Button

Answer (score 0):

You could create some sort of flag `isPopupVisible`, and then check it when you click a button, if it is `true` then `return`, else do the action. You should also set this flag to `true` if popup appears and to `false` when it disapears.